# python command line argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass a command line argument like this because the actual string contains a `#` symbol before and after it

```
python3 test.py #fdfdf#
```

This is the error message I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I pass a string which contains a `#` symbol in the beginning and the end as a command line argument?

Update:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Your operating system/shell would be a relevant detail...

Comment: This is an issue with the shell, so I presume you are using bash? Try using single quotes.

Comment: `python3 test.py "#fdfdf#"` or `python3 test.py \#fdfdf\#`. But as Juanpa said, it's relevant to your shell

Comment: Yeah, I use `zsh` and it works just fine without quotes

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196050/passing-a-bash-command-line-arguments-containing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these and see which one works:

`python3 test.py "#fdfdf#"` or `python3 test.py \#fdfdf\#`